# Access how to show record count of a table on a form

Tags: forms, ms-access

I want to show a variable value (record count of a table) on an Access form. I tried with a textbox by defining its control source with the following and many other internal functions but all returned only errors. Anyone can help? Thanks

```
select count(*) from TableName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `=` and domain functions.

```
=DCount("*", "TableName")
```

should work as control source.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest the `DCount` domain aggregate function as suggested by Andre, but to offer an alternative, if `TableName` is the Record Source for your form, you can also use:

```
=Count(*)
```

To count all records in the Record Source, or:

```
=Count([FieldName])
```

To count all **non-null** values of a particular field in the Record Source.